# Hide Some Of The Categories In Magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.4

I want to hide some of the categories from magento home page. I have created some categories like New Arrivals, Special Offer Which I would like to show in some different way may be in left panel or right side of my home page. I don't want to include them in my top menu. Is There any right way i can do it. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to this screen in your admin interface: `Catalog -> Manage Categories`.

Click on the category in question.

Scroll down.

Set `Include in navigation menu` to `No`.

Done.

Comment: Can U  Help me with this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979149/i-am-getting-a-block-twice-in-magento