# I am getting a block twice in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I am trying to create product block on home page where in I copied page.xml to my theme's layout folder and modified it like

```
<page_two_columns_left translate="label">
<label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Left Column)</label>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
    <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
   <block type="core/template" name="mycategories" output="toHtml" template="sweet/sweet.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```

Here I was expecting one one block in the middle of my Home page and i am getting that but in addition to this i am getting one more block (same as this block sweet.phtml) at the bottom of home page.. below the footer link. Can anyone tell me whats the problem.

Comment: Are you trying replace some block named `mycategories` with your one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've marked your block as an output block. When the view is rendered via `renderView()` in the controller action, your block is both a child of a block which echoes its children (*content* is a `core/text_list` block), as well as being an output block which will be rendered in its own right.

Remove the `output="toHtml"` bit and you will have what you need. By the way, you could / should move this change from a custom page.xml and into a local.xml file in your layout - it need only be inside a `<page_two_columns_left />` layout update handle.

Comment: Great And Thank you... I have copied page.xml into my folder and it gets over ridden. i am making changes there only. Isn't it fine?

Comment: Well, it interferes with the upgrade path. Ideally this kind of change would be made in a local.xml file in your theme's layout folder and you would leave page.xml where it is. Your local.xml would therefore contain <layout><page_two_columns_left><reference name="content"><block type="core/template" name="mycategories" output="toHtml" template="sweet/sweet.phtml"/> <.../>